# Android Studio - No physical Target Device Found cable USB why?

Tags: android-studio, usb

No target physical device I use cable USB why?
I do USB debugging  I allow it from developer option..
I use mac computer
I try change cable or mobile the same problem ?
Can any one help me

physical device show
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6glRS.jpg)

Comment: Did you try type in command line adb kill-server -> adb start-server?

Comment: no how i can do it in mac in terminal?

Comment: Just type it :)